# Where does Gollum (the wiki engine) store its files? (when created via browser)

Tags: git, wiki, gollum-wiki

I've got `gollum` deployed on my server. I set up a wiki directory, seeded it with some files, created a git repo there, then called gollum on the directory.

I can access my wiki via a browser and update and create files. However, I can't find any of the new files or any of the updates in the filesystem.

Are gollum updated files accessible from the command line somewhere?

Comment: It uses a git repository to store the data. If that repo is "bare" there will be no directly visible files. In that case you could use a git tool to look at them.

Comment: @Thilo - thank you. My git config shows `bare = false`. Files are visible, but just the ones I put there *before* running `gollum`. Files I add via the browser don't show up. ----> ...and I just tried running gollum with the `--bare` flag. Now it's displaying updated files! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Thilo thanks again. I was getting my `git` configs confused with my `gollum` configs. Anyway, if you'd like to put in the answer ("files are stored within the git repo"), then I'll check it off. Otherwise, I'll put in the answer in a few days to close out this question.

Answer (score 4):

gollum reads and write to a git repository.

Let's see how it work. The command `git tree` will show commits, branch, and local and remote repository. Let's run it:

```
* 9d80e8f (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) sidebar
* d09d2fe sidebar
* b6f0b07 headers
* 293a8b9 citação
* b2c3723 cronograma
```

The output shows many commits, the first one is the last.

Now let's open gollum, and make some change. To make it simple, let's edit the Home file, clicking on `Edit`. Make any change, and write the commit title as described before saving it:

[image]

Now let's see the repository status and it's tree:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

$ git tree
* d00382c (HEAD -> master) Recomendação para utilizar os links do rodapé
* 9d80e8f (origin/master, origin/HEAD) sidebar
* d09d2fe sidebar
* b6f0b07 headers
* 293a8b9 citação
* b2c3723 cronograma
```

You can see that the commit was made.

**Your first question was**: *Where does Gollum (the wiki engine) store its files? (when created via browser)*

**Answer**: on the git repository by doing commits.

**Your second question was**: *Are gollum updated files accessible from the command line somewhere?*

**Answer**: Your local copy of the file that shows in the working directory is just a copy, it doesn't get loaded by gollum. If you have changed it you can run `git checkout -- filename` to get the last version of it commited at the repostory.

**IF you have setup a bare repository**, it's a bit different. You won't see any copy of regular files, it will be only internal git file. If you want to know how git files are organized I recommend read *[Git Internals PDF](https://github.com/pluralsight/git-internals-pdf)* book.

For example, to list committed files at *master* branch we can use `ls-tree` command:

```
$ git ls-tree master --abbrev
100644 blob 9ca0ea7 "Adicionando-refer\303\252ncias.md"
100644 blob 489ed0b "Apresenta\303\247\303\243o.md"
100644 blob 34d2b6c Baixando um modelo de projeto.md
100644 blob c4a5865 "Citando-as-refer\303\252ncias.md"
100644 blob 7d5bb96 Comandos.md
100644 blob 770917a Como criar elementos.md
100644 blob 5b9b18f "Configura\303\247\303\243o inicial.md"
100644 blob c2c74b7 "Configura\303\247\303\243o.md"
100644 blob 01d7f3e Desenvolvimento.md
100644 blob 1af9d33 Editando-o-texto.md
100644 blob 5f98f2d Editores.md
100644 blob 1bdc46d Esqueleto.md
100644 blob ea80774 Estrutura de arquivos.md
100644 blob b080597 Experimentos.md
100644 blob 7cb4f77 FAQ.md
100644 blob f9fbacd Gerando o PDF.md
100644 blob 1a5bc95 Home.md
100644 blob a548ddc Imprensa.md
```

By the way, that's what @Thilo means by saying: *"In that case you could use a git tool to look at them"*.